# Sound Redirection Program

Tags: audio, window

So whenever I use my computer I am generally playing media on the TV right next to it off of my computer. All programs go out through the sound port over into the sound system. When I'm playing games I generally turn the sound way down in the game so that I get some idea of what is happening in the game without bothering the people that are watching TV. I want to start using a headset so I can chat with people in game while still playing media on my TV however and I'm wondering if there is a program that I can use to easily redirect programs to different sound outputs. I've done some googling on this in the past and have never really turned up anything.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any general way to do it (I assume that you are using Windows), but most programs, especially sound-oriented ones, will have an option somewhere to select which device to use.  Not knowing the specifics of your setup, I would recommend setting your headset as default (for all of the programs that do not have an option) and changing the settings in your media player to use the sound system.